# Trouble adding click event to PyQt5 button, no connect after clicked

Tags: python, pyqt5

fairly new to `PyQt` and Python in general. I am having trouble applying a click event to a button in `PyQt5`. I am trying to add functionality to all the buttons I have, although it seems I am missing some initial setup to allow it to work. Looking through the documentation...

```
pushButton.clicked.connect("Do some action")
```

..should enable the click functionality on the targeted button.
I do not currently have the `connect` option available after the `pushbutton.connect` call.
I assume I am missing some setup in the class.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import cheekycheeky
import datetime
import ntplib
import time

class ContLCDClock(QtWidgets.QWidget,):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateLCD1)
        self.timer.start(1000)

        # self.timer2 = QtCore.QTimer()
        # self.timer2.timeout.connect(self.updateLCD2)
        # self.timer2.start(4000)
        # self.time_format = "%H:%M:%S"
        # self.client = ntplib.NTPClient()
        # self.response = self.client.request('pool.ntp.org')
        # self.clock = time.strftime(self.time_format, time.localtime(self.response.tx_time))

    def updateLCD1(self):
        self.currentTime = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        self.strCurrentTime = self.currentTime.toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.strCurrentTime)

    # def updateLCD2(self):
    #     self.time_format = "%H:%M:%S"
    #     self.client = ntplib.NTPClient()
    #     self.response = self.client.request('pool.ntp.org')
    #     self.clock = time.strftime(self.time_format, time.localtime(self.response.tx_time))
    #     self.ui.lcdNumber_2.display(self.clock)

class Ui_Form(object)    :

    def setupUi(self, Form):

        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(335, 157)

        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 31, 23))
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(print('I am working')) # This does not work


        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 120, 31, 23))
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")


        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 120, 31, 23))
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")


        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 120, 31, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")


        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 16, 80, 19))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")


        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 120, 31, 23))
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")



        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 120, 71, 23))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")


        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 120, 31, 23))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")


        self.lcdNumber_2 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(Form)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(145, 9, 171, 31))
        self.lcdNumber_2.setObjectName("lcdNumber_2")
        self.lcdNumber_2.setDigitCount(11)

        self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(Form)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(145, 59, 171, 31))
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
        self.lcdNumber.setDigitCount(8)


        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 67, 105, 19))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)


    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Cheeky Timer"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("Form", "-.5"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("Form", "-.1"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("Form", "+.1"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "+1"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "NTP Time:"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("Form", "-1"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Reset Time"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "+.5"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Current Time:"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    c = ContLCDClock()
    c.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you in advance for any help, I hope I have been clear enough.

Comment: use `self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(lambda: print('I am working'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be because your input is incorrect, an example piece:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 button - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self)
        button.setToolTip('This is an example button')
        button.move(100,70)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        print('PyQt5 button click')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here a function `self.on_click` is passed. In your example, you pass `print('I am working')`, which returns a `None`. You could fix this for instance like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import cheekycheeky
import datetime
import ntplib
import time

class ContLCDClock(QtWidgets.QWidget,):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateLCD1)
        self.timer.start(1000)

        # self.timer2 = QtCore.QTimer()
        # self.timer2.timeout.connect(self.updateLCD2)
        # self.timer2.start(4000)
        # self.time_format = "%H:%M:%S"
        # self.client = ntplib.NTPClient()
        # self.response = self.client.request('pool.ntp.org')
        # self.clock = time.strftime(self.time_format, time.localtime(self.response.tx_time))

    def updateLCD1(self):
        self.currentTime = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        self.strCurrentTime = self.currentTime.toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.strCurrentTime)

    # def updateLCD2(self):
    #     self.time_format = "%H:%M:%S"
    #     self.client = ntplib.NTPClient()
    #     self.response = self.client.request('pool.ntp.org')
    #     self.clock = time.strftime(self.time_format, time.localtime(self.response.tx_time))
    #     self.ui.lcdNumber_2.display(self.clock)

class Ui_Form(object)    :

    def setupUi(self, Form):

        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(335, 157)

        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 31, 23))
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.i_am_working) 


        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 120, 31, 23))
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")


        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 120, 31, 23))
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")


        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 120, 31, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")


        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 16, 80, 19))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")


        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 120, 31, 23))
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")



        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 120, 71, 23))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")


        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 120, 31, 23))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")


        self.lcdNumber_2 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(Form)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(145, 9, 171, 31))
        self.lcdNumber_2.setObjectName("lcdNumber_2")
        self.lcdNumber_2.setDigitCount(11)

        self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(Form)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(145, 59, 171, 31))
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
        self.lcdNumber.setDigitCount(8)


        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 67, 105, 19))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)


    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Cheeky Timer"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("Form", "-.5"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("Form", "-.1"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("Form", "+.1"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "+1"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "NTP Time:"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("Form", "-1"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Reset Time"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "+.5"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Current Time:"))


    def i_am_working(self):
        print('I am working')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    c = ContLCDClock()
    c.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```